I got a java server online, on vercel, how to make request from it?
I have made a java server locally, it works perfectly with mysql db connection, i choosed to deployed it on vercel and make from it requests both from postman and also from the interface of the web app i am writing, but it gives my only errors.
Here is what comes out from the server deployment on vercel:

Like i told you on local machine it works perfectly with the interface and also with postman, when i put it online no requests work. Can somebody tell me why or how to make it?
I hope somebody could tell me how to put a java server online making requests from it both on deployment and both with postman or locally.

What I see from the documentation it doesn't support Java, so nice that it works locally it won't work for Vercel.

Oh ok, i had to guessed it. can you give me the name of an host for Java server? Better if free

If you want for personal project and don't want to go into infra than go for heroku or railway, if you want for production than any cloud provider with VPC.
